# Orthonormal base for an inner product with parameters

Tags: inner-products, bilinear-form

So I'm given the following bilinear form over $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$$f((x,y,z),(r,s,t))=2xr+axs+bry+cys+3zt$$

where $a,b,c$ are real parameters and I'm asked to find for what values of them $f$ is a scalar product and I've come up with:

$$a=b$$

$$2c>a^2$$

using the definitions of inner product (is that all one can came up with or I've missed some informations ?) however then I'm asked to find an orthonormal base and I really don't know how to proceed further. I know that I have to computer eigenvalues and so on but I can't really figure out how to deal with the parameters.

Comment: Everything here just depends on the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}2 & a & 0 \\ b & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Take *any* basis of $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ and do Gram-Schmidt on it wrt the given inner product...

Comment: If $a=b$ and $2c>a^2$ that is a symmetric, positive-definite matrix and you may easily find its eigenvectors.